# Sequelize/tedious parsing datetime wrong to where clause

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

I am getting no results in sql query because the filter in where clause was changed by sequelize/tedious before query is executed.

```
const query = `SELECT field FROM Table WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CreationDate BETWEEN '${startDate}' AND '${endDate}'`

return sequelize.rawQuery(query)
.then((resultado) => {
    return resultado;
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('error')
});
```

This is the query generated by sequelize/tedious

```
SELECT [Field] 
 FROM [Table] AS [Table] WHERE 
([Table].[CreationDate] > N'2018-02-01 16:36:00.000 -02:00' AND [Table].[CreationDate] < N'2018-02-01 16:46:00.000 -02:00')
```

Can you help me how to solve this? 
CreationDate is stored as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: What are the values of startDate and endDate? Are they strings or date objects?

Comment: Michael, the values are strings for example "2018-02-02 14:45:00".

Answer (score 0):

I have also been banging my head on this for the last week.
It should have been solved [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes)  and has been discussed [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5403) and [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3892). But I don't think it really has been solved.

I know this isn't the correct way, but you could change the schema from this:

```
CreationDate: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  allowNull: true
},
```

to

```
CreationDate: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true
},
```

and then convert your startDate and endDate to integers like:

```
 Date.parse(startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

I really hope someone can help, because the Tedious documentation is kind of hard to understand.
This solved my problem for now, until I fix it. Only ever had this problem with mssql.

Comment: I can't change the datatype on database. CreationDate is a datetime2 field.